# Auto-login on development?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, development-environment

I am relying on a third-party service for authentication (Shibboleth). It is not possible to use this service on the development server since it is running locally and the auth server cannot reach my PC.

So I need to automatically log in with someone's credentials for development. My solution consists of the following. Is there any better/simpler solution in such cases?

`.env`

```
DEVEL_AUTOLOGIN=johndoe
```

`config/devel.php`

```
<?php
  
return [ 'autologin' => env('DEVEL_AUTOLOGIN') ];
```

`app\Http\Middlewave\Autologin.php`

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;
use Closure;
use Auth;

class AutoLogin
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $identity = config('devel.autologin');

        if (!Auth::check() && config('app.debug') && $identity) {
            Auth::login(User::orWhere([
                'id' => $identity,
                'initials' => $identity,
                'lastname' => $identity
            ], true /* remembering */)->firstOrFail());
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

The above middleware is then added to the kernel:

`app\Http\Kernel.php`

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\AutoLogin::class,
        // ...
    ],

    'api' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\AutoLogin::class,
        // ...
    ],
];
```

Comment: Your solution looks sound. You are bypassing `Shibboleth` and performing login manually, what you did solves your problem.

Comment: Yes it does, but it seems cumbersome, isn't it?

Comment: Which part do you find cumbersome? You can't get away without not having a middleware. .env and config files are there to keep things configurable. The only thing that I wasn't sure about is a number of conditions within `orWhere()`... since you have a control you can probably limit login to one of the parameters?